# Activerecord returning all results as a hash

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have the following connecting to a db called dbblah and table1(names changed)

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter => "mysql",
    :host => "192.168.1.10",
    :database => "automation",
    :username => "root",
    :password => "password"
)

ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false

class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
end

db = Table1.find_by(db: 'dbname')
puts db
```

But when I run it, I am getting the results as a hash it looks like:

```
[root@localhost server]# ruby blah.rb
#<Table1:0x000000019796a8>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the output of `to_s` method called on a new object - it is definitively not a hash. By default when calling `puts` method with a non-string, `to_s` method is called on that object to display a string. For ActiveRecord models `to_s` method results in exactely what you got.

Try calling `p db` to display result of method `inspect` called on that object, which will give you more insight in its internal structure.

Comment: I am a complete ruby noob, just started playing with it yesterday. I saw an example somewhere that had "puts" and I just assumed that was the ruby "print".  when I do: p db it works like I would expect. Thanks!